# Using texi2dvi inside R to generate a pdf as a temporary file

Tags: r

I need to generate a pdf from a tex file, as a temporary file. However I'm facing an error. I believe it's due to the fact that the function `tools::texi2dvi` is just a call for the system command with the same name. Since the Rtmp directory just allow R to create files, I can't create the pdf file there.

There's what I'm trying to the, and the error I get:

```
> tf <- tempfile()
> brew("template.brew", tf)
> tools::texi2dvi(tf)

Error in tools::texi2dvi(tf) : 
    Running 'texi2dvi' on '/tmp/Rtmp9n4JFU/filea5811e6a32a' failed.
Messages:
    /usr/bin/texi2dvi: etex exited with bad status, quitting.
```

I believe one workaround would be create a new temporary file using `tempfile()` and ask `tools::texi2dvi` to write the output on it. However I don't know if the system is allowed to edit a file. And also, I couldn't find a way to set `tools::texi2dvi` output file.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `setwd()` to change the working directory before calling `tex2dvi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX is apparently confused by the lack of file extension.
The following should work.

```
tf <- tempfile(fileext=".tex")
cat(
  "\\documentclass{minimal}\\begin{document}test\\end{document}", 
  file=tf
)
tools::texi2dvi(tf)
```

Comment: You're right! Now I could generate the pdf. However, the pdf file is generated into my working directory (home directory) and not into the same folder that the tex file (temporary working dir). Is there any way to set texi2dvi output file?

Comment: That is apparently the indented behaviour of texi2dvi. You can change the working directory before calling texi2dvi, as suggested in Andrie's comment above, and change it back to what it was, after: `oldwd <- getwd(); setwd(tempdir()); ... ; setwd(oldwd)
`